# React Native Navigation with Redux, how to use?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

There are a couple of tutorials online on how to use react-native-navigation with Redux. However, none of them is complete and I really do not understand what do I need to return in my root function.

If I do return

```
<Provider store={mystore}>
<MainScreen />
</Provider>
```

Then, why the need to use `registerComponentWithRedux`?
If I use `registerComponentWithRedux` then I would expect to not to have to wrap my component with the provider again.

Can anyone clarify this, or does any one know a full-complete-working example of react-native-navigation with `registerComponentWithRedux`?

As said, I saw plenty of tutorials online but they do not specify what is returned in the entry file of the application.

Answer (score 2):

[registerComponentWithRedux()](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/third-party?id=registercomponentwithreduxscreenid-generator-provider-store) has been deprecated in favor of [Registering screens with wrapping provider component](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api-migration?id=registering-screens-with-wrapping-provider-component).

The code sample you provide is actually the correct way to do it since the registerComponentWithRedux function has been deprecated. Registering a screen with redux would look something like this ([sample from RNN docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api-migration?id=registering-screens-with-wrapping-provider-component)):

```
Navigation.registerComponent('navigation.playground.ReduxScreen', () => (props) => (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <ReduxScreen {...props} />
  </Provider>
), () => ReduxScreen);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the docs of React Native Navigation -Version2 describes, registering component with Redux goes as below:

```js
Navigation.registerComponent('WelcomeComponentScreen', () => (props) => (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <'WelcomeComponentScreen' {...props} />
  </Provider>
), () => 'WelcomeComponentScreen');
```